# How can I change the default git option from Rebase to Merge in Visual Studio Community?

Tags: visual-studio, merge, rebase

I've been using Visual Studio Community for a few months, and the default option to combine two branches when there are changes in both the origin and destination branches was always "merge changes in current branch".

However, a few weeks ago I got an unrrelated error message that only gave me two options: either "cancel" or "rebase". I accepted to rebase, thinking that it would only apply to that particular case, but instead it also changed the default option from "merge" to "rebase". Whenever I try to combine two branches like I have been doing for these months I don't get anymore the option "merge in current branch", only "rebase in current branch".

I've been trying to change this option in Visual Studio Community configuration, but I don't see that specific option. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

This can be configured in the settings "Source Control > Git Global Settings" and then the drop-down "Rebase local branch when pulling":

[image: Git preferences and settings | Microsoft Learn]

(the image is clickable and will take you to the full documentation)